# Whats wrong with my search string? I am not getting proper data

Tags: django, django-views

I want to implement search on my django project. On my following queryset, with else condition its passing correct data. But with if condition whatever I search, it shows nothing.

```
def get_queryset(self):
 category = self.request.GET['category']
 query = self.request.GET['q']
 if category == 'all':
            products = Products.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(category__name__icontains=query)).all() 
 else:           
             products = Products.objects.filter(Q(category__slug=category),  Q(category__slug__icontains=self.request.GET['q']) |  Q(name__icontains=self.request.GET['q']))
```

Comment: sample data? what are the values of `q` and `category`? you can always check what SQL query is generated from the queryset as well.

Comment: q is user input query string and category will get category slug or 'all'